# How do I remap multi-key sequences to individual keys?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, remapping

I just bought an IBM Model M keyboard. While awesome, it lacks a windows key and multimedia keys. While there are many programs out there that can map one key to another, or one key to a key sequence, are there any programs that will map a keyboard sequence to a single key?

Edit: OS = Win7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Autohotkey.](http://www.autohotkey.com/)

It can map key sequences, macros, mouse input, pretty much anything to a keypress or key combo.

Comment: Does it work in Windows 7 ??

Comment: Yep, it works with all versions of windows back to 9x.  There are different installs for the older versions, though.

Comment: it is kind of very hard to use for a normal non programmer person, the problem I got with this is I am unable to find the name of key I wanted to map lolz, in my case I have a air mouse and I have home key on that, I wanted to map that key with Win+D to show desktop but I dont know the code of that key so what I write in the notepad script, this made this software useless for me even I have programming background, feeling sorry

Answer (score 0):

**Softwares which can map keys are**

- [Sharp Keys](http://www.randyrants.com/sharpkeys/) (Confirmed this works on Windows 7)
- [ZenKey](http://www.camiweb.com/zenkey/)
- [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) (Not sure if this works on Windows 7)
- [Hot Key Plus](http://www.brianapps.net/hotkeyplus/)
- [KeyTweak!](http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/)
- [Hoekey](http://www.bcheck.net/apps/hoe.htm)

Read more about Sharp keys here http://www.question-defense.com/2010/01/14/remap-windows-7-keys-disable-a-key-on-the-keyboard

Comment: As far as I know, this can only re-map single keys. If I am wrong, though, please correct me because I will switch back from KeyTweak!

Comment: oh I didn't knew that, I haven't used it in sequence, OK I updated my answer

Comment: I have used KeyTweak and sharpKey, it only works with single key to single key, Actually I am using a windows 10 pc as my media center/smart tv for my room and i have a air mouse which have android home key(you know what home keydoes in android phone or androidTV) in my windows machine home key opens browser and takes me to home page of the browser, which I wanted to map with Win+D to show desktop and I am unable to do so with both of these softwares, Still looking for a solution