# Remap the F7 key to execute the Win + Shift + S shortcut

Tags: windows, shortcuts, hotkeys, vbscript

I recently reinstalled the Windows on my Xiaomi Mi Notebook Air 13, resulting in a loss of its <kbd>F7</kbd> function - so basically now the <kbd>F7</kbd> key does nothing!

I have also found out that Windows currently has a really efficient way of creating a screenshot by using the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> shortcut, which copies to clipboard a selected region of the screen. My idea is to remap that <kbd>F7</kbd> key to this functionality, but I have a problem!

I already tried writing VB script to execute this key combination, however, VB script's SendKeys doesn't support Windows key - so I guess this option is impossible. So I am thinking, does any of you knows exactly what Windows executes to run this feature? I am also opened to any other suggestions, as well!

P.S. I use WinHotKey for shortcut management.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I've just remapped my PrintScreen button to Win+Shift+S using the Keyboard manager on Windows Power Toys.

https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys

I've used AutoHotkey before and this would do the same job but Power Toys is simpler and quicker I'd say... WPT also has a lot of other nice functionality so it's worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.technorms.com/31627/how-to-remap-your-keyboard) article provides some useful ways of remapping keys, here are some useful tidbits from the article:

Sharpkeys:

> SharpKeys is a program that’s brimming with features. It’s a keyboard
>   remapper that offers an easy-to-use interface. All keyboard remaps are
>   saved permanently, when using SharpKeys, since it adds values to the
>   appropriate registries. A restart of the computer is required for
>   keyboard changes to take effect.

Keymapper:

> Thanks to its large keyboard graphic, Key Mapper is one of the easiest
>   key remappers you can use. When using this tool, the keyboard graphic
>   will take up most of your screen, making it easy to see.

As mentioned in the article, make a system restore point first, so you don't lose everything if something goes wrong. 


Enjoy your keymapping!

Edit: The IBM website provides [useful info on key mapping](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/hostondemand/library/v8infocenter/assignkey.html) that should help you out.

> Keyboard remapping lets you associate a sequence of keystrokes with a
>   particular action, so that typing the sequence of keystrokes causes
>   the action to occur. The sequence of keystrokes can be either a single
>   key or a single key combined with Shift, Ctrl, or Alt. The action can
>   be to display a character, to execute a host function, to execute a
>   custom function, or to execute a menu command.

[Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) is a good resource as well, Apparently it can do multi-key combinations. According to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/186103/how-do-i-remap-multi-key-sequences-to-individual-keys) question, it can

> [...] map key sequences, macros, mouse input, pretty much anything to
>   a keypress or key combo.

And [this](https://superuser.com/questions/745052/how-to-remap-a-single-specific-key-to-a-windows-shorcut?rq=1) question gives some more details and resources.

If you can't get it to do a full winkey+shift+s function, maybe have it do winkey+shift, and press "S" yourself?

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! However, the problem is that I want to remap the key to a whole key combination - not an individual key. My idea was if you know a way to see what Windows runs when I press Win + Shift + S, and to run the same thing with a script, which I will then map to the F7 key

P.S. I tried to mimic such functionality with keymapper, but couldn't do it :/

Comment: @IvanPanchev Couldn't you just get it to run "Snipping tool"?

Comment: I can - that's easy - but what I particularly like is this way of taking screenshot without any additional UI - it's like opening Snipping tool and pressing new at once

Comment: @IvanPanchev Check out the edit I made, maybe that can help

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a keyboard macro which causes <kbd>F7</kbd> to send <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

One simple (though a little techie) way to do this is with the free tool [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/).

1. Install Auto Hotkey
2. Open Notepad, and enter put the text below, then save it in $Home\$Documents\AutoHotkey.ahk  -  This tells AutoHotkey to listen for <kbd>F7</kbd> and whenever it is typed, to inject <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>

`F7::Send #S`

Alternatively, if you want it to behave a bit more like the mac, and have <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> trigger the region screenshot, then put this in the file:

`!$::Send #S`

3. run AutoHotkey.exe from C:\ProgramFiles\AutoHotkey\AutoHotkey.exe

If you want AutoHotkey every time you startup, run regedit, and add the registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
New -> String Value
Name = AutoHotkey
Value = "C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\AutoHotkey.exe"
```