# How can I map a key on Windows to a key combination (like Ctrl + PrtScr)

Tags: windows, keyboard, macros, hotkeys

Basically I want the ability to temporarily rebind my <kbd>M</kbd> key to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd>.

Comment: Have a look at AutoHotkey>>>>>https://www.autohotkey.com/

Comment: The thread [How do I remap multi-key sequences to individual keys](https://superuser.com/questions/186103/how-do-i-remap-multi-key-sequences-to-individual-keys) lists some softwares which can help remap keys. You can have a try to see which one is more suitbale for you.